# Efficient way to get number of times each line has changed in a Git repostiory

Tags: python, git

I want to get how many times each line in each file of a Git repository has changed in a window of past commits.

My current approach is to use the command `git --no-pager diff --name-only HEAD~<N>..HEAD` in the root directory to get a list of files that have been modified in the past `N` commits. Then, for each line of each file, use the command `git --no-pager log -L <LINE_NUMBER>,<LINE_NUMBER>:<FILE_NAME> --no-patch HEAD~<N>..HEAD` to get the commits that modified the line `LINE_NUMBER` of the file `FILE_NAME`. For example, if there is one such commit, the output looks like this:

```
commit 6420233aa9e280c70de303369e5e8d1d9e4d7b2b
Author: Joe Bloggs <joe@bloggs.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 16 12:00:00 2022 -0000

    Commit message.
```

I then just count the number of times a line in the output starts with "commit" to determine how many times the line has been modified in the past `N` commits. Here is my Python implementation:

```
import subprocess as sp


def get_changes_file(commit_window, file_name):
    l_no = 1
    changes_file = {}

    while True:
        proc = sp.run(
            [
                "git", "--no-pager", "log", "-L", f"{l_no},{l_no}:{file_name}", 
                "--no-patch", f"HEAD~{commit_window}..HEAD"
            ],
            encoding="UTF-8", stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE
        )

        if proc.returncode:
            expected = f"fatal: file {file_name} has only {l_no - 1} lines\n"

            if proc.stderr == expected:
                return changes_file

            proc.check_returncode()

        lines = proc.stdout.splitlines()
        changes_l_no = sum(l.startswith("commit") for l in lines)

        if changes_l_no:
            changes_file[l_no] = changes_l_no
            
        l_no += 1


def get_changes(commit_window):
    stdout = sp.check_output(
        [
            "git", "--no-pager", "diff", "--name-only",
            f"HEAD~{commit_window}..HEAD"
        ],
        encoding="UTF-8"
    )

    changes = {}

    for file_name in stdout.splitlines():
        if os.path.exists(file_name):
            changes_file = get_changes_file(commit_window, file_name)

            if changes_file:
                changes[file_name] = changes_file

    return changes
```

The output of `get_changes` is a dictionary mapping file names to dictionaries mapping line numbers to the number of times they were modified in the past `commit_window` commits.

My implementation seems to work, but is extremely slow for moderate to large repositories (especially when the commit window is large). So my question is, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: How can you track line  with line added or removed ?

Comment: @Ôrel I'm using this to just broadly identify parts of the project with a lot of recent changes. I know it's arguably a bit imprecise when lines are added or removed but it's not a big deal for my use case, particularly when the commit window is relatively small.